# Sonarqube fails to start after reboot

Tags: java, linux, sonarqube, ubuntu-18.04

I don't get much information from `systemctl status:`

```
sonar.local.lab sonar.sh[4471]: Gracefully stopping SonarQube...
sonar.local.lab sonar.sh[4471]: Removed stale pid file: ./SonarQube.pid
sonar.local.lab sonar.sh[4471]: SonarQube was not running.
```

From **/var/log/sonarqube/es.log**

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: can not run elasticsearch as root
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.initializeNatives(Bootstrap.java:107) ~[elasticsearch-7.17.4.jar:7.17.4]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.setup(Bootstrap.java:183) ~[elasticsearch-7.17.4.jar:7.17.4]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:434) [elasticsearch-7.17.4.jar:7.17.4]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:166) [elasticsearch-7.17.4.jar:7.17.4]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.execute(Elasticsearch.java:157) [elasticsearch-7.17.4.jar:7.17.4]
        at org.elasticsearch.cli.EnvironmentAwareCommand.execute(EnvironmentAwareCommand.java:77) [elasticsearch-7.17.4.jar:7.17.4]
        at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.mainWithoutErrorHandling(Command.java:112) [elasticsearch-cli-7.17.4.jar:7.17.4]
        at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.main(Command.java:77) [elasticsearch-cli-7.17.4.jar:7.17.4]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:122) [elasticsearch-7.17.4.jar:7.17.4]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:80) [elasticsearch-7.17.4.jar:7.17.4]
2023.11.01 16:26:49 ERROR es[][o.e.b.ElasticsearchUncaughtExceptionHandler] uncaught exception in thread [main]
```

**/etc/systemd/system/sonar.service**

```
[Unit]
Description=SonarQube 9.6.1.59531 service
Requires=network.target
After=network.target network-online.target
Wants=network-online.target

[Service]
Type=forking
User=sonar
Group=sonar
ExecStart=/my/custom/path/sonarqube-9.6.1.59531/bin/linux-x86-64/sonar.sh start
ExecStop=/my/custom/path/sonarqube-9.6.1.59531/bin/linux-x86-64/sonar.sh stop
ExecReload=/my/custom/path/sonarqube-9.6.1.59531/bin/linux-x86-64/sonar.sh restart
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=10
PIDFile=/my/custom/path/sonarqube-9.6.1.59531/bin/linux-x86-64/SonarQube.pid
LimitNOFILE=65536

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I have verified the user and group `sonar` is owner of owner of every file under `/my/custom/path/...`

I don't know why elasticsearch complains about running as root. Yes, I try to restart the service running:
`systemctl restart sonar`, however, from the `sonar.service` file, woulnd't this be run a the sonar user and group?

Comment: What is the RUN_AS_USER property set to in the sonar.sh script?

Comment: Such property does not exists.  `grep RUN_AS_USER /my/custom/path/sonarqube-9.6.1.59531/bin/linux-x86-64/sonar.sh`

Comment: Sorry they eliminated that property with v9.6.1.

Comment: From https://community.sonarsource.com/t/sonarqube-will-not-start-due-to-elasticsearch-being-unable-to-write-yml-settings-file/15643. Turns out the temp/conf files was owned by root. I just `chown -R sonar:sonar`. Probably not the correct way of solving this issue (long term), but it works.